# Run the [automobiles] off the road!

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, burninate-request

[automobiles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/automobiles)

26 questions about... cars. In fact, I'm not sure why [some questions even have the tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51041253/doip-tcp-a-pair-of-port-numbers). You've even got to admire [the excerpt](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/755280)

> An automobile, autocar, motor car or car is a wheeled motor vehicle used for transporting passengers, which also carries its own engine or motor. Most definitions of the term specify that automobiles are designed to run primarily on roads, to have seating for one to eight people, to typically have four wheels, and to be constructed principally for the transport of people rather than goods.

This isn't helpful to programming questions. Let's crash this party.

Comment: The tag excerpt makes it all the more obvious that it has no place here: *An automobile, autocar, motor car or car is a wheeled motor vehicle used for transporting passengers, which also carries its own engine or motor. Most definitions of the term specify that automobiles are designed to run primarily on roads, to have seating for one to eight people, to typically have four wheels, and to be constructed principally for the transport of people rather than goods.*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I went through most of the questions. In most of the questions, the tag is added because the question contains something remotely related to automation ([and isn't describing the contents of the question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging)). It certainly does not add any meaningful information to the post.

As there are less than 50 posts, this qualifies for the quick-burnination. Therefore do go ahead and start the burnination. Here are some quick links to get you started:

- [Open](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bautomobiles%5D+closed%3Ano)
- [Closed](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bautomobiles%5D+closed%3Ayes)
- [Unanswered](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bautomobiles%5D+answers%3A0+closed%3Ano)
- [No Accepted Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bautomobiles%5D+hasaccepted%3A0+closed%3Ano)